# How do I convert a string array to an int array?

Tags: php

I am creating a school Software in PHP and I have a couple of subject ids which were implored using the implore() function and inserted in the db, delimited by commas(,).I retrieved them and they are a string e.g when I var_dump it's showing that it's a string.

Example:

```
$subjId = $class_data['subject_ids']; 

var_dump($subjId) // string(6) "9, 4,5,"
```

Note that it's commas are also counted.

How do I use each number in the string, or convert the string into an integer array? I want to match each number to its respective subject from a subjects table and then output the subject names.

Comment: Is the sujects table a database table, too? Then you don't need to convert the "string numbers" to integers. You just can query like this:
SELECT subject_name FROM XY WHERE subject_id = '$number'
The database will not care if $number is a integer or a string.

Comment: Could be as simple as `array_map('intval', explode(',', $class_data['subject_ids']));`

Comment: I tried array_map('intval', explode(',', $class_data['subject_ids'])); it's actually converting all IDs to a single digit number, e.g //945.  @Andreas the $class_data['subject_ids'] is a result from a class table, where a user has created a class, and then selected subjects for that particular class. I don't have problems with to echo $class_data['class_name'] because it's a string, but the question above is that I want to further use each number. I tried  SELECT from subjects_table WHERE id = $class_data['subject_ids']... Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It's simple when you have implode() your array into the string $subjId you can use this code to convert it into array of int :

```
$arrayOfInt = array_map('intval', explode(',', $subjId));
```

In example :

```
$subjId = '9, 4,5,';

 $arrayOfInt = array_map('intval', explode(',', $subjId));
 
 var_dump($arrayOfInt);
```

Result of var_dump :

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(9)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(5)
  [3]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Comment: For loop in the array you can use foreach for example or array_map.

foreach( $arrayOfInt as $key => $value ){
//do what you want
}

full explain here : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Help me to loop through that array, because it's been converted into a single block number when you remove  the commas (,)